# Integrate[x Tan[x], {x, -1, 1}] with NDSolve

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to solve with `NSolve`

```
Integrate[x Tan[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

and get the numeric value.

`NIntegrate` works well.

```
NIntegrate[x Tan[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

and get 0.85617

For `NDSolve` I do

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == x Tan[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, -1, 1}]
```

Can please somebody give me a tip where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
y[x] /. NDSolve[{y'[x] == x Tan[x], y[-1] == 0}, y, {x, -1, 1}][[1]] /. x -> 1
(* 0.856177 *)
```

General way:

```
a = -2; b = 3;
f[x_] := Sin[x]^3
y[b] /. First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == f[x], y[a] == 0}, y, {x, a, b}]
(* 0.274443 *)
y[b] - y[a] /. First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == f[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, a, b}](*By comment: @user64494*)
(* 0.274443 *)

NIntegrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]
(* 0.274443 *)
```

Comment: Or y[1] - y[-1] /. NDSolve[{y'[x] == x*Tan[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, -1, 1}] .

Comment: @user64494.(+1) Yes ,thanks.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk and @user64494 remark: `NDSolve[{y'[x] == x Tan[x], y[-1] == 0}, y[1], {x, -1, 1}][[1]] (*{y[1] -> 0.856177}*)` works too!